# Can LaTeX embed PDF into the QR code too?

Tags: pdf, qrcode

In this [package](https://ctan.org/pkg/qrcode?lang=en), where strings, or texts are embedded into QR code. I recently learned that we can also include PDF into a QR code.

Many online site does not provide this service for free.

I am wondering if LaTeX can embed existing PDF into the new QR code?

Thanks.

Comment: the only way I know would be a very small pdf encoded as a data: URI which could then be QR encoded just like any other URL string but it would have to be a very small pdf. Unless you have a link to a different embedding?

Comment: And that PDF contains a QR code generating itself?

Comment: PDF at its basic level used to be wrapped PS text, the QR limit  for Kanji/Kana = Max. 1,817 characters so with a overhead of say 67 English header and eof characters that would give say 1750 on a simple page layout for English it would be over 4250 letters inc spaces

Comment: Unfortunately the standard is not a QR code itself as its 117 pages https://www.iso.org/standard/62021.html  (someone else may have the code that links to the PDF :-) ps forgot to add QR codes can be chained but are not supported as such by the package per the ctan doc

Comment: @Symbol1 that can be done as you query however base 64 images are twice as costly as the text its conveying not sure if any text based compression would be any better

Comment: Maybe  SVG is the way to go since that fits well with pdf here is a short example trimed from an amimated cloud   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="loader" viewBox="0 0 46 33"><g class="asd" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-width="1"><path class="cloud" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M 45 22.7331 C 45 31.3109 L 36.3341 31.3109 C 41.1201 31.3406 45 27.4871 45 22.7331 L 45 22.7331 Z" /> <path class="loop" stroke-linecap="round" d="M 25.3571 17.8209 C 26.0155 17.1208 27.1653 15.6667 29.5168 15.6667 C 32.1278 15.6667 34.2444 17.6366 34.2444 20.0667 C 25.3571 17.8209" /></g></svg>